# In simulator, app is blank (white), but appears normal when quit?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

So I'm new to programming but I'm managed to create the groundwork for an iPhone app.

Problem is, when I run it on the iPhone simulator, it first shows up as a white/blank screen (with the status bar at the top) until I hit the home button. When it is doing the minimization animation (~0.5 second) the app will display correctly.

I know that an issue with versions could be the cause of this but I'd need to buy a newer Mac to upgrade to the latest version of Xcode. If there are other issues that could be causing this I'd love to know

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Default.png image to your application and see if it shows that during loading. Run the app in debugger and add a breakpoint to viewDidAppear in your viewController. It's probably running but not loading in the view you are expecting it to for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

To some viewcontroller's view your are not setting the background color as clear color .. that's why it is showing blank white screen when your application is launching .. if your are using xib .. set the background color of that view to clear color using interface builder.